# How to SetFetchSize throughout application in java Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao

In a spring application i developed has 30 dao classes
Consider the below code

```
public void getBulkData(List<Integer> patients, Date start)
{
        Criteria criteria = getSession()
          .createCriteria(DafCondition.class, "condition")
          .createAlias("condition.patient", "dp")
          .setFetchSize(100000);
}
```

i have about 30 dao classes similar to this in my application, how do i setFetchSize(100000) for all criteria throughout the application in one go ?

Thank you

Comment: You dont. You could refactor your code for DAOs to share the same common base, or use static utis to set required parameters. But anywa, every class will be edited one way or another.

Comment: because this gets a lot tedious when there are like 10s of DAO classes. I'll try this but each class has to be edited differently so it defeats the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the motive behind setting the value "in one go" as you mentioned?
Is it purely from a maintenance perspective, that you want to change the value at one place and everywhere it is reflected? If yes, the just move the value `100000` as a constant in a static class/interface and use it everywhere.

Comment: Nah OP just don't want to make obvious changes in 30 classes - I think it took more time and effort to write that question than actually doing the refactor eg. in manner you have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

you can extends Session and overrite createCriteria method with adding fetchsize.